# I want to switch solar panels between a micro inverter and a backup system. How can I do that?

Tags: switches, inverter, solar-cell, backup

Solar Inverters are switched off during a blackout and make that you have DC electricity on your roof while being without AC in your home. This may not be as urgent where you live, but in countries like Mexico and others, blackouts are more common. In such a case, I want to be able to use the DC electricity from the solar panels convert it to AC store it and generate 120VAC for the house. Assuming that I want to switch the panels between micro inverter and backup system, a DC 50V 15Amp switch is required for each panel.

I want to connect the solar panels between two different systems, namely a micro inverter and a backup system. The switching between these two systems must be automatic. I assume modern solar panels can produce 550W STC at around 50V and 15A. How can we switch solar panel outputs was/is my question?

1. The first thing that comes to mind is a relay that can switch 15A - 50VDC and is equipped with either SPDT or DPDT contacts. Such relays exist, but DC arcing makes them large and not cheap, at least from what I have been able to find.
2. Another possibility is SSR relays, but they only come in SPST configuration and have a voltage drop of 1-2V. They are suitable for string configurations but not for a single panel, as they result in significant power loss per panel, and they need cooling.
3. The remaining option is a MOSFET DPDT switch. MOSFETs come in various types and sizes, have a low RDSon, they can switch large currents at high voltages, and are not affected by arcing and contact aging. However, to my knowledge, such a switch does not exist as a ready-made product in the market.

This is roughly the decision-making process I went through, and I have decided on the last option. I have designed a DPDT switch that can be controlled with a dry contact. Below, you can see the design that I tested in MultiSim Spice.

At the bottom left under Pan2, you can see schematically what the circuit on the right does. The circuit is essentially a DPDT switch consisting of two SPDT switches which are simultaneously controlled. The switch referenced "switch" in the schematic represents a mocro controller controlled dry contact that switches one of the two systems. T13 T14 T23 T24 control the gates of the MOSFETs.

**This is my question:**

Before I proceed with building this, I would like to know if there are people who have other or better ideas on how to make a solar switch. Perhaps people have experience with what I describe here. Maybe someone knows a product in the market that does this. If you know a product I would like to hear it. If you have better ideas, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to switch in the first place? Why can't they share DC bus as drawn in your schematic?

Comment: @winny Many/most PV inverters do not provide isolation between the grid and the panel. As such, any time the inverter is operating, the panel is live at mains voltage.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica Ah! That makes sense. How about PV -> inverter with isolation to AC -> AC/DC for the backup system? No switchover needed.

Comment: MI = micro inverter || Q1. What is you max price and size for a commercial 48V 20A relay? They exist. || Q2a Can the microinverter be disabled while still fed with DC? I'd expect so. If so the DC can be left connected.  Q2b same question for secondary inverter || Q3 would it be acceptable to place a DPDT AC relay in the output of the MI  If so it can still accept DC input BUT will draw very little current as it does not "see" AC mains and so will not start.

Comment: ||Q4 Is it unacceptable to leave the u-inverter as is with DC and AC connected? It will not run with no AC on output.  || Q5 IMPORTANT - Is output AC of backup inverter connected to home AC that MI usually powers? If so  how is the AC switched between them. OR do you manually switch the loads?  ||Q6 PV panel can be disabled by opening one leg, then switching inverters, then closing open leg. Would this help? || Q7 IF the mains input can be removed from the MI then it can be "spoofed" with an AC source to make it run. This may not be acceptable from regulatory point of view.

Comment: **IF** MI DC input is isolated from AC mains you only need a SPDT switch or 2 x SPST switches. (If it's not then you could use 4 x SPST switches or relays if that makes the task easier.

Comment: Your switching concept seems OKish BUT MAY need work in practice. MAY be OK - I'd need to play. Did you simulate this. || You'll want change over deadtime.  |||| What change-over time  is acceptable. A mechanically driven switch may work well enough. All the amps and volts you want with a motor driven knife switch. A servo would make this easy.

Comment: A better/simpler choice is surely to either a) buy an inverter that already has this built in - commonly called 'hybrid grid-tie inverters', or b) have two separate sets of panels.

Comment: @Wogoos If you want good answers then answering questions asked by others is "a very good idea". It MAY be that information revealed by your answers re what is acceptable MAY reveal a quite different good solution.

Comment: You know you can buy battery backup DC/AC inverters [that support AC-coupled pv systems](https://www.victronenergy.com/live/ac_coupling:start)?

Comment: Thanks all of you for your responses. I understand your remarks regarding the AC side but that is not my point I want to switch the DC side of the panels away from the micro inverters to an alternative system that acts as a backup in my case, but it can be any other system. This requires a relay function that can handle 50Vdc 15Amp capacity with a DPDT or SPDT contact configurations. I haven't found a relay like that that can handle these currents and voltage and that is smaller than my design I propose here.

Comment: @Wogoos  I suspect it may be useful to you to have a close look at my and other comments above and to answer the questions asked. || What you are trying to achieve was and is understood. The intent of my questions was to ascertain whether what you wish to achieve can be done without the solution that you have decided is essential. ie IF the microinverter makes no power and draws minimal output when it is not grid-synchronised and/if it can b disabled by some input when still DC powered AND IF your standby system can be enabled/disabled by other means than connecting DCpower THEN a control ...

Comment: ... level implementation would be suitable. || I strongly suspect that this is the case, or that it could be with minimal effort. || || Very high current shrouded (for safety) knife switches are available at low cost. A motorised system to drive these could be implemented at modest cost and probably with reasonable effort.

Comment: Sorry @russel McMahon, I might have not answered some of your question because they were not related to the question had, but let me answer the ones that are related. Yes, I have simulated it for one single panel and for two panels in string configuration and guess what the simulation tell me is that it works. Regarding your idea to use relays, yes that crossed my mind too, however I didn't find 50V 15A DC relays that has an acceptable price and size. Your ideas to use separate panels is not acceptable because the extra panels will only work for less than 5%of the time to charge the batteries.

Comment: @wogoos It's reasonably likely that you cannot be sure that the questions that you think are irrelevant are in fact irrelevant. There are certainly some which relate to solutions that MAY suit you, but while they remain unanswered we'll never  know. Answering most of them would be trivially easy and it's not obvious that you have much to gain by not answering them. || SSSM' suggested separate panels. I can't imagine that I would have done so. (Stranger things occasionally happen :-) ).  ||